# Add chess piece on particular chess board position, using for loop

Tags: php

I want to add chess piece on B4, chess piece is a link of PNG image.
the board is 8x8 created by for loop, I am sure I could use more advance for loop technique, I am beginner in PHP. Any help appreciate it

```
<body>
    <div class="board">
        <?php $j=0; for($j=0; $j<4; $j++) :?>
            <?php echo "<div class='row'>"; ?>
                <?php $i=0; for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++):?>
                    <?php
                    echo
                    "
                    <div class='white'></div>
                    <div class='black'></div>
                    ";
                    ?>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
        <?php echo "<div class='row'>"; ?>
            <?php $k=0; for($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++):?>
                <?php   
                echo 
                "
                <div class='black'></div>
                <div class='white'></div>
                ";
                ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
        <?php endfor;?>
    </div>

    //link I will use to display chess piece
    <img src='http://classes.codingbootcamp.cz/assets/classes/33/pieces/whites/king.png' alt=''>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I see what you're doing here, in order to have white and black squares alternate, but it does make your next job (working out which square you're currently outputting HTML for) extremely difficult.

You're better off doing a nested `for` loop, each with 8 iterations; the outer one for rows, and the inner one for squares in each row.

Doing a nested `for` loop might seem more complicated to the beginner, but it's actually a much more accurate representation of what a chessboard looks like - an 8x8 grid - which then makes it much easier to think about.

Another great example of using a nested `for` loop, which is almost exactly the approach you should be taking here, have a look at this example where a 10x10 multiplication square is output: https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-for-loop-exercise-10.php

You can use the modulus (`%`) operator to decide whether to make the square black or white.

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    echo $i % 2;
}
// Will output 01010101...
// ... so if 0 is white and 1 is black...
```

You'll have to add the value of the current row AND the current square, and then use the modulus operator, to differ the position of black/white squares on each row.

Then, for doing something special with your B4  square, it's just a case of a simple `if` expression:

```
if ($row == 2 && $square == 4) {
    // Output chess piece HTML
}
```

(In this case I've assumed you've started the loop iterations at 1, but it's more common in PHP and other languages to see loops starting at 0 because that's how array structures are numbered. And of course, row B here, the second row, is row 2.)

As I can see you're learning, I've not spelled out the answer for you here, but you and others should hopefully find this helpful.